# How can I disable touch screen when loading ActivityIndicator in React Native?

Tags: javascript, android, ios, reactjs, react-native

I want to disable touch screen when loading (I use ActivityIndicator). I put `pointerEvents = {'none}` but it's not working. Can you give me a solution about this ?

```
import React from "react";
import { TouchableWithoutFeedback, View, ActivityIndicator } from "react-native";
import Colors from "../../resources/colors/Colors";

const AppProgress = () => (
    <View pointerEvents={"none"}
      style={{
        width: "100%",
        height: "100%",
        backgroundColor: Colors.dimBlack,
        position: "absolute",
        alignSelf: "center",
        justifyContent: "center",
        alignItems: "center"
      }}>
      <ActivityIndicator size="large" color={Colors.green}/>
    </View>
);

export default AppProgress;
```

**Version:**

> react: 16.4.1 => 16.4.1
>   react-native: 0.56.0 => 0.56.0

Answer (score 2):

You have done every thing correctly, just can you try zIndex of high value in the view styles, as some other view might be overlapping it.

Answer (score 0):

```
export const OverLayLoading = () => {
return(
    <View style = {styles.overlayLoadingContainer}>
        <ActivityIndicator
            size={50}
            animating={true}
            />
    </View>
 )
};


  overlayLoadingContainer:{
    position: 'absolute',
    top: 0,
    bottom: 0,
    right: 0,
    left: 0,
    justifyContent:'center',
    alignItems:'center',
    zIndex: 1,
    backgroundColor: 'black'
 },
```

Answer (score 0):

Component

```
export const CustomActivityIndicator = () => {
      return (
        <View style={styles.activityIndicatorBody}>
          <ActivityIndicator  size="large" color='blue' />
        </View>
      );
    };


const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  activityIndicatorBody: {
    position: 'absolute',
    left: 0,
    right: 0,
    top: 0,
    bottom: 0, 
    width: '100%',
    height: '100%',
    zIndex:10,
    backgroundColor: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.0)',
  }
});
```